# Can Hangouts limit the number of SMS messages for specific contacts?

Tags: sms, google-hangouts

One of my SMS contacts has several thousand messages; I'd like to limit the number of messages per contact to a much smaller number (my prior SMS app had a per-contact setting).  I found an option "Delete old messages -- delete old messages when storage is low" and enabled it, but it hasn't helped.

Is there a way to limit the number of SMS messages kept by hangouts?